# Generic "back" button in a MVC3 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a good way to create a generic back button in my asp.net MVC3 application?

For the moment, I have a different action on each of my button and when there's more possibilities, I add redirectTo in the Url so I can redirect back to this Url. It not the best solution since I have to add every possibility and I will probably forget to add it to a specific form.

I also taught of using `History.Back` in js but sometimes it will redirect to a form that will redirect back to an other (as an exemple the list of inscriptions redirect to add an inscription if there is no inscription, then clicking on the back buttons should redirect to the list of inscriptions if there's is at least one inscription but to the list of courses if there's no inscription). The back button will also close a popup sometime.

Maybe it could be something in a BaseController that would execut on the `OnActionExecuting()` or something in the Global.asax like a `GlobalFilter`?

Any idea of how I could do this?

Comment: Do you use any kinds of MVVM pattern?

Comment: Most browsers have a generic back-button already implemented. What's wrong with that?

Comment: It's a Chrome App so there's no button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did finaly is to overwrite the button in javascript :

```
    $('.cancel-btn').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        history.back();
    });
```

It works fine, even for the double redirection, it get back to the first page and not to the one that redirect to the last one. Since it's an application and you have to loggin first, you will almost always have a page to go back to.

Comment: Amazing. this should just like, be the standard for back buttons.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Request.UrlReferrer` to easily access where a user has come from.

You could have something along the lines of:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location='@Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri'" >Back</button>
```

However the `UrlReferrer` will not be available if the user has directly navigated to the page.

Comment: And it won't work for the cases where there is a auto-redirect in my page (like an empty list that redirect to the create item) will return back to an empty list and then this page will redirect again to create a new item

Answer (score 2):

```
<a class="back_button" href="@Request.UrlReferrer"><i class="icon-circle-arrow-left"></i>@ViewResources.ShipingLine.back</a>
```

You can use href="@Request.UrlReferrer" to back page first step.

I have already tested it and it working well.

Avtandil kavrelishvili